# Using Email for Username in ASP.NET Framework 4 Forms Auth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, formsauthentication

I want to use the built in Forms Authentication in an MVC 4 app using Framework 4.5.

However I can't seem to override the the username field - even if I edit the account model and set the username to say 255 Maxlength it's still creating the table with a max of 56 - and thus I can't use an email address for the password.

I've decorated the UserProfile thus:

```
 [Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User name (Email)")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?("")("".+?""@)|(([0-9a-zA-Z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-zA-Z])@))(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}))$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address.")]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: "it's not working" is not a proper error message.

Comment: No, but 'even if I edit the account model and set the username to say 255 Maxlength it's still creating the table with a max of 56' is an error description ;-)